# How can I encode and decode query values

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, node.js, express

My present "Restore objects pickled into JSON strings" Express.js function is:

```
router.post('/restore', json_parser, function(request, response, next)
  {
  console.log('router.post /load');
  console.log('Body: ' + request.body);
  console.log('Query: ' + request.query);
  console.log('href: ' + sanitize(request.user.href));
  console.log('identifier: ' + sanitize(request.query.identifier));
  var result = look_up_identifier(request.user.href, request.query.identifier);
  console.log(result);
  response.type('application/json');
  response.send(result);
  });
```

The Ajax save() function on the client-side, which is presently not being reached, is:

```
var save = function(identifier, data)
  {
  if (Modernizr.localstorage)
    {
    localStorage[identifier] = JSON.stringify(data);
    }
  jQuery.ajax('/save',
    {
    'data':
      {
      'data': JSON.stringify(data),
      'identifier': identifier,
      'userid': userid
      },
    'method': 'POST'
    });
  }
```

The server is giving a 500 page and my client-side restore() function, available on request, is responding to being given non-JSON input (in this case, the jqxhr.responseText begins with a '<' if the server gives a 500 response). The server debugging console.log()s are giving [object Object]:

```
router.post /load
Body: [object Object]
Query: [object Object]
href: httpsapi.stormpath.comv1accounts[identifier deleted]
POST /restore 500 7.343 ms - 1202
router.post /load
Body: [object Object]
Query: [object Object]
href: httpsapi.stormpath.comv1accounts[identifier deleted]
POST /restore 500 3.410 ms - 1202
router.post /load
Body: [object Object]
Query: [object Object]
href: httpsapi.stormpath.comv1accounts[identifier deleted]
```

And the localStorage directory is empty.

I would like to be able to send values via Ajax, whether by QUERY_STRING in a POST body, or as JSON, and pick out on the server side whatever I've encoded on the client side. Something's failing, and I have not yet gotten a dictionary where I probe for one of the keys from the client-side and get a regular value back out from what I have encoded via QUERY_STRING or JSON.

What do I need to be accomplishing differently?

Comment: Do you have any bodyparser middleware installed? what is json_parser?

Comment: Your console.logs could be changed to be a bit more helpful. Instead of concatenating your strings with an object, use a comma. `console.log('Body: ', request.body)` Now you'll actually be able to see data (or the lack thereof)

Answer (score -1):

You can use EncodeUriComponent() Javascript function to encode special caracters, try it:

```
var encodedString =  encodeURIComponent(/* your string here */);
```

Comment: I worded the question ambiguously, sorry. I'm not concerned about how to encode for URI's; I'm concerned about how to get ANYTHING out of the QUERY_STRING or JSON I sent from the client-side.

Comment: jQuery does this for you, if you're talking about the client-side.